# How to display error messages to user in AsyncTask in Android?

Tags: android, exception, android-asynctask

I am using `AsyncTask` to get the data form a web service that I created. Now I want to display proper error messages to user like if the Internet is not available it will display toast for that similarly if server is down it will display toast for that. I want to set a string with error like "server is down" or "internet problem occured" in doInBackground() and display Toast in onPostExecute() but I want to know if my server is down that what exception is thrown? and if my server is active but during transfer internet is disconnected so what exception is thrown ?

Comment: Yes you should of course catch all those exceptions.

Comment: In doInBackground() you cannot use Toast(). Do that in onPostExecute().

Comment: yes i know i will set a string will error in doInBackground() and display Toast in onPostExecute() but I want to know if my server is down that what exception is thrown? and if my server is active but during transfer internet is disconnected so what exception is thrown ?

Comment: Well try it out and you will see. All you can find in the LogCat.

Comment: What classes and methods are you using to connect to the Internet? You should look at the documentation for these. The docs will tell you exactly what exceptions can be thrown by each method.

Comment: save the server status and with every status show some message in onPostExecute()

Answer (score 0):

Probably modelling the response is the best and easiest way.

For example,

you can compose a model from the data you got such as:

```
   class ApiResponse {
          public final String responseString;
          public final Throwable error;

        public ApiResponse (String responseString,Throwable  error){
          this.responseString  = responseString;
          this.error = error;
        }
    }
```

Then, you can bind response or error to that model and return from `doInBackground();`

Pseudo code :

```
class ApiAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ApiResponse> {
    ....

    protected ApiResponse doInBackground() {

        try {
            //callApi and get response, if success pass null in error
            return new ApiResponse(responseString, null)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            //otherwise pass that error
            return new ApiResponse(null, e);
        }
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ApiResponse apiResponse) {
        //now just need to check if error is null 
        if (error == null) {
            String json = apiResponse.responseString;
            //parse response   
        } else {
            //get error and check with instanceOf
            Throwable error = apiResponse.error;
            if (error instanceOf SocketTimeoutException){
                //show timeout error
            }
            else if (error instanceOf SomeXYZException){
                //handle that exception
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is just an example. You can put anything you want in `ApiResponse` and compose model of that data. (such as status code got from api, generated pojo class of json response by some converter etc. anything).  Once you have the data bounded, you can use it in `onPostExecute()` as it will always be running on your UI thread. Note that Third type param `Result` of `AsyncTask` is built for that by definition : [`AsyncTask<Params, Progress, Result>`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Answer (score 0):

Catch exceptions of your `doInBackground()` to string and than, depends what you need, you can show toast message from `onPostExecute()` method, something like this:

```
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {

try {
            // do you stuff here


        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "UnknownHostException: " + e.toString();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            response = "IOException: " + e.toString();
        } finally {
           ...

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        if (response.contains("IOException: java.net.ConnectException:")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        else if (response.contains("IOException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException:")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
        else if (response.contains("IOException: java.net.SocketException:")) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "YOUR TEXT HERE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
        }
}
```

Of course, this is yust an example, but you could see how that can be worked out.